# macOS Calendar search doesn't work for future events

Tags: macos, calendar, spotlight, search

Spotlight search finds future events, but macOS Calendar search (top right corner search field) does not.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried on my Calendar v11

By only typing the first letter it shows groups of:

- People
- Location
- Title
- Notes

So it works perfectly fine all the way in 2024.

> [image: test]

> [image: more]

Comment: No it doesn't work for me. Same Calendar  version. Create an event at the middle of 2024. Give it title ASDFASDF. Go to today. Use the search field and write "ASDFASDF". If you see results, I'd love to see a screenshot. Mine shows "No Results"

Comment: @user3722246 posted the result in my answer

Comment: Thanks. Mine still doesn't work. I even followed the example I gave you. What's your macOS version or macbook type? What might be the reason mine isn't working?

Comment: @user3722246 MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) Monterey v12.7---I have 3 CalDav accounts, 2 gmail and iCloud

Comment: @user3722246 at the moment I do not know why yours is not working, just testing on mine